# How to publish .nupkg to Powershell Gallery?

Tags: powershell, autorest, powershellget

### Solution

Credit to [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0)

Here's what I ended up doing to publish my `bin\MyModule.0.1.0.nupkg` module to PSGallery:

1. Rename `bin\MyModule.0.1.0.nupkg` to `bin\MyModule.0.1.0.zip`
2. Extract `bin\MyModule.0.1.0.zip` to `bin\MyModule\` (the name of the extracted folder had to match the name of the `.psd1` file inside, so in my case there was now a `bin\MyModule\MyModule.psd1` file).
3. Delete the `[Content_Types].xml` file from inside the extracted folder (not deleting this causes an error when you try to download and install the module from PSGallery, seemingly caused by 2 copies of that file being present in the resulting `.nupkg`).

Then I was able to run this command:

```
PS> Publish-Module -NuGetApiKey xxx -Path .\bin\MyModule
```

And it worked! My module is now published to PSGallery.

### Original Post

I have a Powershell module generated and packaged as a .nupkg file by [Autorest.Powershell](https://github.com/Azure/autorest.powershell). I now want to publish my module to the [Powershell Gallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/), but can't figure out how to get it to work.
I have tried:

```
PS> Publish-Module -NuGetApiKey xxx -Path .\bin\MyModule.0.1.0.nupkg
Publish-Module: The specified path '.\bin\MyModule.0.1.0.nupkg' is not a valid directory.

PS> Publish-Module -NuGetApiKey xxx -Path .\bin\
Publish-Module: The specified module with path '.\bin' was not published because no valid module was found with that path.

PS> Publish-Module -NuGetApiKey xxx -Name .\bin\MyModule.0.1.0.nupkg
Get-Module: C:\Users\bport\Documents\PowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\2.2.5\PSModule.psm1:10630
 Line |
10630 |  …   $module = Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name …
      |                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      | The specified module 'D:\workarea\bin\MyModule.0.1.0.nupkg'
      | was not found. Update the Name parameter to point to a valid path, and then try again.

Publish-Module: The specified module '.\bin\MyModule.0.1.0.nupkg' was not published because no module with that name was found in any module directory.

PS> dotnet nuget push .\bin\MyModule.0.1.0.nupkg --api-key xxx --source https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2
Pushing MyModule.0.1.0.nupkg to 'https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2'...
  PUT https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2/
  MethodNotAllowed https://www.powershellgallery.com/api/v2/ 580ms
error: Response status code does not indicate success: 405 (Method Not Allowed).
```

Publishing .nupkg files to Powershell Gallery should be possible because you're able to download packages from Powershell Gallery as .nupkg files. Additionally, the Autorest documentation says [this](https://github.com/Azure/autorest.powershell/blob/b48827fc7225f243a1a170abb277e1c3040b3e07/powershell/resources/assets/how-to.md#packing-projectmodulename) about its generated nupkg files:

> The structure of the .nupkg is created so it can be loaded part of a PSRepository. Additionally, this package is in a format for distribution to the PSGallery.

I'm guessing this is possible, but I just can't figure out how to do it. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I believe the way you are trying to do it with `Publish-Module` requires that the module NOT be packaged.  It will do the packaging for  you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of version 2.2.5 of the `PowerShellGet` module - the one that comes with preview versions of PowerShell 7.2 - the [`Publish-Module`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/PowershellGet/Publish-Module) cmdlet for publishing PowerShell modules to the [PowerShell Gallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/) does *not* support uploading `.nupkg` files.

Instead, it requires a (non-compressed) *directory* containing the PowerShell module to publish<sup>[1]</sup>, which is *then* compressed into a (temporary) NuGet package (`.nupkg` archive) behind the scenes and uploaded to the gallery.

I'm not familiar with AutoRest.PowerShell, but if it claims that the `.nupkg` archives it creates are compatible with the PowerShell Gallery you can try to *extract* (uncompress) such an archive (NuGet files are ZIP archives, so you can pass them to [`Expand-Archive`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.archive/expand-archive)) into a directory and try to pass that directory's path to `Publish-Module`'s `-Path` parameter (choose the directory that contains the module manifest file (`.psd1`), which may be a subfolder).

---

<sup>[1] If the module to publish is located in one of the directories listed in `$env:PSModulePath`, its directory location can be inferred from the module's *name*, passed to the `-Name` parameter.</sup>