# Is it possible to Install-Module from public GitHub Packages location?

Tags: powershell, github-actions, github-package-registry, powershell-module

I have been able to successfully publish a PowerShell module of my own creation to the [repo's](https://github.com/beau-witter/NetworkAnalyzer) [GitHub Packages location](https://github.com/beau-witter/NetworkAnalyzer/pkgs/nuget/NetworkAnalyzer). I have [utilized](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/gallery/how-to/working-with-local-psrepositories?view=powershell-7.3&viewFallbackFrom=powershell-6) [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66250711/how-to-publish-nupkg-to-powershell-gallery) [resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/powershellget/register-psrepository?view=powershell-7.3) [to get that accomplished](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/powershellget/publish-module?view=powershell-7.3).

The problem comes in after that. I cannot seem to be able to run `Find-Module` and get anything from the specified registered PSRepository.

If I delete the package so there are no collisions, I can register a PSRepository with the GitHub Package location:

```
Register-PSRepository -Name GitHub -SourceLocation https://nuget.pkg.github.com/beau-witter/index.json -PublishLocation https://nuget.pkg.github.com/beau-witter/index.json -InstallationPolicy Trusted
```

and then publish to that Repository without issue:

```
Publish-Module -Path path/to/module -Repository GitHub -NuGetApiKey "<GITHUB_API_KEY>"
```

If I run that publish again, I will receive the error:

```
Write-Error: Failed to publish module 'NetworkAnalyzer': 'nuget.exe failed to push Response status code does not indicate success: 409 (Conflict). '.
```

Indicating that the first publish was successful and now can't put the same package at the same version in that location.

However, running `Find-Module -Repository GitHub -Credential $BuiltCredentialObject` I just receive null back. Everything on the GitHub page for [Working with the NuGet registry](https://docs.github.com/en/packages/working-with-a-github-packages-registry/working-with-the-nuget-registry) seems to explicitly assume this is going through a .NET project/or solution with .csproj files and running `dotnet`. Besides that, the actual steps for installing seems pretty hand-wavy and unclear. [This NuGet Issue on GitHub](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/8948) seems to suggest it can be done:

> Can GitHub act as a PSRepository which would make PowerShellGet commands see it as a PSRepository?
>
> In theory, yes. See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/gallery/how-to/working-with-local-psrepositories?view=powershell-6

But again, that is dealing almost entirely with Publishing, not consuming.

Is it possible to actually consume the valid PowerShell modules from the GitHub Packages NuGet package repository?

Answer (score 0):

While digging deeply within each of my provided resources, I found a diamond hiding in all the information that failed to help me before.

In this [StackOverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71245752) the user adds a link at the bottom of their answer that takes you to [this comment on a GitHub issue for PowerShellGet](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShellGet/issues/163#issuecomment-803058766).

After updating my PSDepend to add PowerShellGet as a dependency (allowing for Prerelease), and following the pattern laid out in the PowerShellGet Issue comment

```
Register-PSResourceRepository -Name GitHub -URL https://nuget.pkg.github.com/beau-witter/index.json
Install-PSResource -Name NetworkAnalyzer -Repository GitHub -Credential $BuiltCredentialObject
```

I am able to consume the PowerShell Module from the GitHub Packages NuGet repository!

So it seems that, for the time being, consuming PowerShell Modules from a GitHub Packages NuGet repository may only be possible in Powershell 7+ using the beta of PowerShellGet v3.

Edit: More details. It appears that GitHub Packages is [still not officially supported even with PowerShellGet v3 (beta)](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShellGet/issues/992). So this solution only currently works on a Windows machine. I do not know the lowest version this works on, but 3.0.19 beta19 of PowerShellGet does allow to run `Install-PSResource` with GitHub Packages as the repository.

Note: The `secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN`, even with Read-Write, appears to not be authorized to the GitHub Packages NuGet repository, so a sufficient PAT is still necessary.